# Remove duplicate first names from a full name in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider the following data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:3, Name = c("Xiao-Li Meng, Michael Drake, Jennifer Chayes, Chayes, Michael Jordan, John DeNero, Ani Adhikari, Jordan, Mia Scher", "Nenshad Bardoliwalla, Bardoliwalla, Alex Woodie", "Jill McKeon, Jan Nygaard Jensen, Hongyu Zhao, Xinxin (Katie) Zhu, Clive R. Wood") , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like to remove the duplicates First Name/Last Name if the Full Name is available in the String. Also, no changes made to the string if there is no match. The result should be like the data-frame provided below;

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:3, Name = c("Xiao-Li Meng, Michael Drake, Jennifer Chayes, Chayes, Michael Jordan, John DeNero, Ani Adhikari, Jordan, Mia Scher", "Nenshad Bardoliwalla, Bardoliwalla, Alex Woodie", "Jill McKeon, Jan Nygaard Jensen, Hongyu Zhao, Xinxin (Katie) Zhu, Clive R. Wood"), UniqueName = c("Xiao-Li Meng, Michael Drake, Jennifer Chayes, Michael Jordan, John DeNero, Ani Adhikari, Mia Scher", "Nenshad Bardoliwalla, Alex Woodie", "Jill McKeon, Jan Nygaard Jensen, Hongyu Zhao, Xinxin (Katie) Zhu, Clive R. Wood") , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Any Inputs will be really appreciable.

Comment: I see that you accepted my answer, but your new example is not covered by my answer given that you added the name `Jan Nygaard Jensen`. In that case, my code will not work, because it will treat in `Jan Nygaard` (or `Jan Jensen`, or `Nygaard Jensen`) as a full name and thus never exclude it. If that's fine, then my code is fine. If that's not fine, then you may want to clarify the opening post a bit more.

Comment: It's fine. I am looking for a solution, which will work with either First Name/Last Name duplicates removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

Use grepl to find strings that [1] do not contain a space, and [2] are present in other names.

**Code**

```
df$UniqueName <- sapply(df$Name, function(x) {
  sn <- unlist(strsplit(x, split = ", ", fixed = TRUE))
  sn2 <- sn[!(!grepl(" ", sn) & sapply(sn, function(y) sum(grepl(y, sn)) > 1))]
  paste(sn2, collapse = ", ")
})
```

**Rationale**

We use `sapply` since each entry needs a lot of work. We essentially perform 3 steps: [1] split the string with `strsplit`, [2] subset to keep only those that you want, [3] paste the string back together with `paste`.

The reasoning here is that single first or last names do not contain a space, and if they are present in other names then you want to remove them. Hence, we find those that do not have a space (`!grepl(" ", sn)`) and that are a substring of another entry (`sapply(sn, function(y) sum(grepl(y, sn)) > 1)`). Then, we remove those using `[!( )]`.